# Using PHP to select table entries using two date fields and current month

Tags: php, date

Please help a newbee. I have a table named event_calendar with fields named ec_start_date, ec_end_date and ec_event_name. The first two fields are date fields. It is a small table, with less than 100 entries. I want to list events with a start or end date in the current month, then I want to follow with a list of events with a start or end date in the next month. The two list will be headed by the month name. I would like the dates displayed in the list to be in the format dd/mm.

This is the code I've found to identify the months for the list headers.

```
$thismonth = mktime(0,0,0,date("n"));
$nextmonth = mktime(0,0,0,date("n")+1);

echo "<h2 class='caps'>";
echo date("n", $thismonth);
echo "</h2>";

echo "<h2 class='caps'>";
echo date("m", $nextmonth);
echo "</h2>";
```

This is the code I use to pull the entries for this month's (August) activities

```
$query = "SELECT ec_display,ec_event_name,ec_start_date,ec_end_date FROM event_calendar WHERE month(ec_start_date) = 8 OR month(ec_end_date) = 8 ORDER BY ec_start_date";
```

The problem is, if I replace the number 8 with the variable $thismonth, it fails.

Finally, how can I display only the dd/mm from ec_start_date and ec_end_date?

I greatly appreciate any guidance, but please be specific as I am very new to this! Thank you!

Comment: What is the error that is being generated if you replace the 8 with $thismonth?

Answer (score 0):

`$thismonth` contains a UNIX timestamp returned by `mktime`. The timestamp for hour 0, minute 0, second 0 of month 8 of this year is 1312862400. That's not 8.

Don't put that in your query, put `date('n')` (8) in it... or just let MySQL do it

```
$query = "SELECT ec_display,ec_event_name,ec_start_date,ec_end_date FROM event_calendar WHERE month(ec_start_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) OR month(ec_end_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) ORDER BY ec_start_date";
```

Comment: Wow Dan, thanks for the quick response!  Your suggestion works great, how can I pull the list for next month using month(current_date)?

Comment: Try `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`.

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm getting all emotional because I'm so grateful for the help.

Comment: Can I ask for one more thing? How to display only the month and day from the ec_start_date and ec_end_date?

Comment: In your PHP code after retrieving the row from the query, you can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format the dates however you want, as you did with the month numbers earlier. For example, `echo date('F jS', strtotime($row['ec_start_date']));` to get something like "August 9th".

Comment: Thanks again Dan, you're a hero!